# Perfmon HyperV Logical Processor Frequency is incorrect

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v

When HyperV role is enabled on a windows server or workstation, the reporting of the CPU's frequency in taskmgr is no longer useful.

The solution is clearly outlined in [KB3003081](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3003081)

However, I am seeing on my Win 8.1 machine that this counter reports the stock frequency of the CPU. CPU-z shows anywhere from 1.6ghz to 3.2ghz

And on a 2012 R2 machine it is reporting 0

Both machines are Windows 6.3.9600

How can I monitor the CPU frequency on a HyperV enabled computer?

Answer (score 4):

There's not much you can do here except what you already did. Good wrap up and fully story with a lot of links here (it also references KB you provided link to):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/danchar/2014/09/20/physicallogical-cpu-frequency-reporting-with-hyper-v-enabled/

Comment: Its a bit sad, how many admins around the world open up taskman to confirm their hyperv is running at '2.6ghz' - when in actual fact it could be running at more like 1.2ghz.
Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to rely on a little trick that 7zip seems to be able to pull off - it is able to 'sense' the CPU frequency.

```
C:\Temp>7z b

7-Zip 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03

CPU Freq:   2064   4000   4266   4000   2723   3282   3631   3282  3357
```

The final figure is the CPU speed (turbo in my case). This approach works from inside a hyperv guest also.